# Uploading images to S3 using NodeJS and Multer. How to upload whole file onFileUploadComplete

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, multer

I'm using *NodeJS* and *Multer* to upload files to *S3*.

On the surface, everything appears to be working, the files get uploaded, and I can see them in the `bucket` when I log into the *AWS* console. However, most of the time when I follow the link to the file, the file is broken, often the file size is much smaller than the original file.

When the file reaches the server, the file size is correct if I `log` it, but on *S3* it is much smaller. For example I just uploaded a file which is 151kb. The `post` request logs the file size correctly, but on *S3* the file says it's 81kb.

Client side:

```
uploadFile = (file) ->
    formData = new FormData()
    formData.append 'file', file


    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open "POST", "/upload-image", true
    # xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data");

    console.log 'uploadFile'

    xhr.onerror = ->
        alert 'Error uploading file'
    xhr.onreadystatechange = ->
        if xhr.readyState is 4
            console.log xhr.responseText

    xhr.send formData
```

Server:

```
app.use(multer({ // https://github.com/expressjs/multer
      inMemory: true,
      limits : { fileSize:3000000 },
      rename: function (fieldname, filename) {
        var time = new Date().getTime();
        return filename.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase() + '_' + time;
      },
      onFileUploadData: function (file, data, req, res) {
        var params = {
          Bucket: creds.awsBucket,
          Key: file.name,
          Body: data,
          ACL: 'public-read'
        };

        var s3 = new aws.S3();
        s3.putObject(params, function (perr, pres) {
          if (perr) {
            console.log("Error uploading data: ", perr);
          } else {
            console.log("Successfully uploaded data", pres);
          }
        });
      }
    }));

    app.post('/upload-image', function(req, res){
        if (req.files.file === undefined){
            res.end("error, no file chosen");
        } else if (req.files.file.truncated) {
            res.end("file too large");
        } else {
          console.log(req.files.file.size); //logs the correct file size
          var path = creds.awsPath + req.files.file.name;
          res.type('text/plain');
          res.write(path);
          res.end();
        };

    });
```

EDIT:

Setting `file.buffer` to the `body` perma `onFileUploadComplete` seems to work, but I have a feeling that this isn't the proper way of doing things, and may come back to bite me later. Is this approach okay, or are there issues I should be aware of doing this?

Comment: `onFileUploadData` is triggered for chunks of data received. Should be `onFileUploadComplete`

Comment: oh you are using `putObject` to upload those chunks

Comment: aha... so perhaps if I store the file in memory, and then on complete do the put object... I'll try that, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @hassansin onFileUploadComplete I get the file, but do you know what I set as the 'Body' on the putObject params? If I put it as 'file' then that doesn't work.

Comment: you can use `s3.upload` function to upload the whole file.

Comment: @hassansin aha, onUploadComplete using file.buffer as the 'body' peram works. I guess this isn't the 'correct' way of doing things though? Couldn't work out s3.upload.

Comment: In case anyone is still reading this or this other post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763448/node-js-aws-s3-file-upload-how-to-get-public-url-response?rq=1, know that multer no longer supports the callbacks used here like onFileUploadData(). See the docs for the current options - https://github.com/expressjs/multer.